# Is this apparent story about how Julius Caesar selected soldiers true?

Tags: julius-caesar

I heard a suggestion that Caesar would select the soldiers he wanted by leading them, thirsty, to a river and seeing who would simply plunge in to take a drink vs. who would first get a cup and fill it with water. Apparently, he preferred the divers...

I've searched quite extensively and have found no evidence for this claim. I am no expert, so I thought I'd ask if anyone is aware of this practice.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a process he used repeatedly or just something he did once?

Comment: Since the Roman legions had thousands of soldiers, this does not sound like a practical method. Perhaps he did it once to prove a point.

Comment: Caesar didn't select soldiers.  See [ACOUP:Dilectus](https://acoup.blog/2023/06/16/collections-how-to-raise-a-roman-army-the-dilectus/) There was a procedure for filling a legion.  What's the source for this story? is it all all credible?   History is about sources....

Comment: That's a biblical story, Judges 7. (https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%207&version=ISV)

Comment: @Jos You should just post that as the answer.

Comment: @MCW the source is by no means credible in a rigorous sense, the story stems from a statement in a documentary about composer Harry Partch. I am preparing notes on the documentary, so am checking the statements he makes. Interesting that it at least exists in some form (as a Biblical story). Maybe he forgot the exact details...

Comment: Are you aware that Caesar had *tens of thousands* of soldiers under his command? He surely did not "select" them personally.

Comment: I'm just wondering why Caesar would bother to personally be present to select thousands and thousands of soldiers. He's running an entire empire.

Comment: My dad once told me of a corporate executive officer who, when interviewing job candidates, would have a "present" staged on a cabinet near the door. As the candidate entered the office, the exec would casually ask, "would you mind bringing that package to my desk and unwraping it?" Any candidate who took time to save the wrapping paper, then would have a short, polite chat with the exec, and would not be called back.

Comment: @DKNguyen: Regarding *running an entire empire*, Caesar commanded several military expeditions as *imperator* long before being appointed dictator or seizing power in Rome.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's normal though when losing control of the military means losing control of the state.

Comment: @SolomonSlow What's the point of that?

Comment: @DKNguyen, substitute "corporate executive" for "Julius Caesar," "job candidate" for "recruit," "wrapped present" for "river," etc. I'm suggesting that it's a meme. The same story gets told and re-told, maybe even since before the Bible version. The shape of the story changes, but the message stays the same: Bold leader gets the job done, and doesn't \*\*\*\* around when seeking followers who can get jobs done without \*\*\*\*ing around.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

#### No, not true.

That's a direct copy of a biblical story, [Judges 7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Judges%207&version=ISV). In that story Gideon has to select his soldiers. He has too many volunteers. The Lord leads them to drink at a river. There the Lord selects for Gideon the 300 men he needs out of a multitude of soldiers. The 300 where the ones that rushed to the water and drank from their hands.

I haven't heard that story about Julius Caesar. It must be an apocryphal story, because that is not how [Romans selected men](https://www.quora.com/How-were-Roman-soldiers-selected-and-what-kind-of-training-did-they-receive) for the army. The selection process was not that much different from what we practice today. Recruits were inspected, checked by medical orderlies or a doctor for physical and medical problems. How you drank water was not a requirement.

Something else that makes it very unlikely: Julius Caesar was far too important to be personally involved in the selection process himself. He just gave an order 'raise a legion in province x'. His officers would do what was required. He had too many jobs to manage to be bothered with such a tiny insignificant detail. His job was to appoint the officers and centurions. He knew them well, and most by name. It was the job of a centurion to go out and get recruits.

Comment: The way I read this, this story is not about rushing to the river, or the drinking of water per se, but about maintaining a higher level of situational awareness while drinking water: (1) The ones that kneel down to drink are considered unfit to be soldiers; (2) The ones that use their hands to scoop up water are considered fit to be soldiers.

Comment: @njuffa That's your interpretation, but that is not how Romans selected soldiers. Feel free to add something to back up your interpretation.

Comment: It's strange how memory works. I've the clearest memory of this being a three-fold test, with first the fearful, secondly those who knelt to lap lie a dog, and thirdly those who failed to keep their free hand on their sword hilt, being sent home, before Gideon had only 300 men. And then recalling, as a young adult, thinking: "Yes! The psychopaths! That's exactly the 300 you want for a suicide mission." But there' no version of the Bible I can find with any such third test.

Comment: @Jos I was not referring to the Romans in my comment, but to the Bible passage referenced in the answer (+1). In other words: my comment was meant to augment, not contradict. And the test as described in the Bible makes perfect sense: those that crouch, upper body upright, one hand on their weapon, the other hand used to scoop water, are immediately ready to fight in case of an ambush.

Comment: @njuffa thanks for explaining. Interpretation is the reason why there are +30.000 varieties of Christianity. :-)

Comment: @Jos the story is from the old testament, so it is independent from Christianity... of course, one could equally say that in every synagogue they have their own interpretation of Tanakh :)

Comment: @njuffa The more things change, the more the ones that don't stand out...

Comment: @Jos wonderful, thank you for this information! The story, which comes from casual conversation in a documentary, just seems to be apocryphal but at least exists in some form, which is mildly interesting. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @njuffa The way I always read it, it had very little to do with any attributes of the soldiers themselves and everything to do with God wanting a very small group of people to demonstrate His power (and His alone) through

Comment: Related to the Biblical story (and I'd have to find my source -- Ray Vanderlaan, I think?) I've heard it explained that this is similar to e.g. Elijah's complaint that very few Israelites remained who were not idol-worshippers; kneeling was the practiced pose for idol-worship, and so those 300 who refused to kneel to drink were 'the only faithful'

Comment: Also, given the numbers of men that Caesar did mobilize, I do not think he could afford to be picky. Certainly he prefered well trained veterans, but he had to gather whatever he could. To the point that he got in trouble when several legions, who had been serving under him longer than they should have been mobilized, did mutiny and reject further orders.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp - apparently the 300 "lapped" the water, which might be difficult standing or crouching

Comment: @Henry The 300 who were kept were the ones who brought the water to their mouth with their hands. The ones who knelt down to put their face in the water to drink (and were sent away) were the other ~10,000. But I also highly doubt that kneeling/bowing/prostrating in a random place would be at all related to idolatry, mostly because that's not indicated as the reason for rejecting that majority, and it would have been specifically called out if it were, since Israel's troubles with idolatry is a huge point of the book of Judges.

Comment: The story about Caesar certainly does resemble the passage from Judges about Gideon. The latter may be the source of the former, but not necessarily. Sometimes stories (and events) resemble each other for other reasons. (And even if the Gideon story is the source of the Caesar story, calling it a "direct copy" is a bit of an overstatement, given the difference in details.) I only bring this up because some popular historians are too quick to jump to the conclusion that one narrative is a copy of another, when there are other plausible explanations for the resemblance.

Comment: For example, Jesus' feeding of the 4,000 in Matthew 15 resembles the feeding of the 5,000 in Matthew 14. Some scholars assume that one story is a copy of the other. But it's more plausible that they were just two similar events. Jesus even compared the two events in Matthew 16:9-10 as if they were two separate occurrences.